# Trying to read callouts, how to get value of /IT from PdfDictionary in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to read the callout text boxes in a PDF.  I'm using iTextSharp to iterate through all the annotations as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace PDFAnnotationReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\J123\Desktop\xyz.pdf";
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
            PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            for (int i=0;i<annotArray.Size;i++)
            {
                PdfDictionary curAnnot = annotArray.GetAsDict(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Examining the `hashMap` of `curAnnot`, I see that when I get to an annotation that is a callout text box, the dictionary includes the following key-value pairs:

```
{[/IT,/FreeTextCallout]}
{[/Contents,xyz this is a callout]}
```

So I think what I should do is check each annotation to see if it includes the key `/IT` with the value `/FreeTextCallout` and if so, get the value of `/Contents` as a string like so:

```
if (curAnnot.Contains(PdfName.IT))
{
    if (curAnnot.Get(PdfName.IT)==PdfName.FREETEXTCALLOUT)
    {
        Console.Writeline(curAnnot.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS).ToString());
    }
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be a `PdfName.IT` or `PdfName.FREETEXTCALLOUT`.  How do I check for the existence of `/IT` and retrieve its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `PdfName` objects using the constructor on `PdfName`:

```
new PdfName("IT");
```

So:

```
var myPdfNameIT = new PdfName("IT");
if (curAnnot.Contains(myPdfNameIT)) {
    //...
}
```