# how to get the author of a PDF annotation

Tags: pdf, annotations, itext

Is it possible to get the author of a free text annotation using iText?

I have the TYPE and CONTENTS, but can see noway to get the author

Answer (score 4):

Please consult ISO-32000-1 table 170 "Additional entries specific to markup annotations". It defines a key named `/T` that is described as an optional *text string* that *shall be displayed in the title bar of the annotation's pop-up window when open and active. This entry shall identify the user who added the annotation.*

KenS is correct in the sense that the value you seek is not available for every type of annotations, but if the author is present, you'll find it in the `/T` entry.

So when you have this in Adobe Acrobat:

[image]

You'll find this inside the PDF:

[image]

You already have the `/Contents` and `/Type` entry, now you should also look for the `/T` entry. If it is missing, the author of the annotation can not be retrieved.

These are some examples on how to get specific keys from an annotation:

- [Reading hyperlinks from pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959076/reading-hyperlinks-from-pdf-file)
- [Trying to read callouts, how to get value of /IT from PdfDictionary in iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126997/trying-to-read-callouts-how-to-get-value-of-it-from-pdfdictionary-in-itextshar)
- [Advanced PDF parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449903/advanced-pdf-parser-for-java)
- ...

I'm adding these links only for the sake of completeness, I think you already know the concept:

```
PdfDictionary annotDict = annots.getAsDict(i);
PdfName author = annotDict.getAsString(PdfName.T);
```

If `author` is `null`, the author can not be retrieved.

Comment: thank you.. as ever your detailed knowledge shows it's worth. I had read the tables from 171 so missed what is now clear as the blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

While you can specify extra keys in a dictionary, which will usually be ignored, there is no 'Author' key in an annotation or FreeText annotation in the specification.

So you can't get the author of a FreeText annotation, because its not normally part of an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the T key like so

```
PdfString Author = annot.GetAsString(PdfName.T);
```

Comment: This is @Bruno's answer burnt down to its essential tip.